# Python - Pandas '.isin' on a list

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm using Python 2.7 on Mac OSX Lion and Pandas 0.11.0 with the IPython shell.

I have a brief issue, using the data selection method `.isin`.

The issue is that I would like to use `.isin` on a list of items, so:

```
data = df[df[header[0]].isin(list)]
```

I get the following error when I do this: `KeyError: u'no item named '`

I generate the initial list by calling a previously developed function.  I tried using `eval` on the list, which seems to solve an issue that comes about when using `raw_input` and iterating over items within it - kinda trying to work out some of the issues I've been having when transitioning to `IPython` and `Python 2.7` (originally used `Python 3.3`).

I also tried iterating over the list, by first doing:

```
data = df[df[header[0]].isin(list[0])]
```

But that also returns: `KeyError: u'no item named '`

UPDATE:
Here is the header:

```
 Unnamed: 0         9752  non-null values
 zipcode            9752  non-null values
 xcoord             9752  non-null values
 ycoord             9752  non-null values
 age_age5064        9752  non-null values
 age_age6574        9752  non-null values
 age_age75plus      9752  non-null values
 sex_female         9752  non-null values
 sex_male           9752  non-null values
 stage_early        9752  non-null values
 stage_late         9752  non-null values
 death_death        9752  non-null values
 death_not_death    9752  non-null values
 access             9752  non-null values
 dtypes: float64(2), int64(12)
```

Also, I have a function I use to get the header, which makes things easier for me, the output looks like this:

```
['',
  'zipcode',
  'xcoord',
  'ycoord',
 'age_age5064',
 'age_age6574',
 'age_age75plus',
 'sex_female',
 'sex_male',
 'stage_early',
 'stage_late',
 'death_death',
 'death_not_death',
 'access']
```

Which, actually, now that I think about it, may be what is causing the problem- although `eval` still would not fix it.

UPDATE 2:

So, initially, as you can see in the above `.isin`, I was using `header[0]`, which was not right.  I tried again using `header[1]`, which is appropriate.  I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I also tried the regular list again and got this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

Which, I guess, speaks more definitively to the issue....

Comment: Is your `header` a DataFrame?, What's the difference between your `df` and `header`?

Comment: Within the `df[df[header[0]].isin(list)]`, header is not a `DataFrame`.  It is a list of the column names, which compose the header.

Comment: How did you get the header? By `df.columns`?

Comment: I got the header by calling a function I wrote called `getHeader`, which literally just returns the name of the columns, in the form of a list, from a CSV file.

Comment: Although, I did also put the result of calling `DataFrame.columns`, which is right below where it says "UPDATE"...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30798/discussion-between-waitingkuo-and-fortylashes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use df.columns as your header instead:

```
df[df[df.columns[1]].isin(list)]
```